# Creating drop down menu and form in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to create a drop down menu that allows a client to search users by a field specified in the drop down menu. For example, search by state, search by city, etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
<p>Search options:</p>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/get/{value}" method="get">
    <select>
        <option th:value="AllUsers">Search all users</option>
        <option th:value="ByUsername">Search by user name</option>
        <option th:value="ByFirstname">Search by first name</option>
        <option th:value="ByLastname">Search by last name</option>
        <option th:value="ByAddress">Search by address</option>
        <option th:value="ByCity">Search by city</option>
        <option th:value="ByState">Search by state</option>
        <option th:value="ByZipCode">Search by zip code</option>
        <option th:value="ByPhoneNumber">Search by phone number</option>
        <option th:value="ByEmail">Search by email</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" th:field="value" name="searchField"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="searchButton"/>
</form>
```

I'm just not sure how to connect the `action` and the `value` tag of the currently selected item in the drop down list to specify the URI. If a user selects, search by state, and he enters in "Maryland", how do I specify the corresponding URI tag?

This would be my method in Spring that executes the action:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/ByState", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getByState() {
    // ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/get/ByCity", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getByCity() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have just the required answer in this link:

http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-form-select-tag/

Comment: This article in the link uses JSP, not Thymeleaf

Comment: Not using thymeleaf.

Answer (score 7):

Because the accepted answer is not using Thymeleaf and this question is top in Google I'm adding my solution here.

In my situation `statues` is a list of Enum values. Model attribute is populated as usually you do in Spring:

```
mav.addObject("statuses", EnumSet.allOf(Status.class));
```

Group has a filed of type Status (the enum).

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
        <option th:each="stat : ${statuses}"
                th:value="${stat}"
                th:text="${stat}"
                th:selected="${stat.equals(group.status)}"/>
    </select>
</div>
```

This automatically populates the list and selects value that is selected in my Group instance:

[image]

Comment: what is group here && what  what does group.status imply ?  Is group a keyword in thymeleaf /

Comment: It's in the answer: Group has a filed of type Status (the enum

Comment: yes thanks.. with this change I am able to display the selected value on the UI, but the remaining values in the ENUM are not getting populated ? Is there a way to do that ? Now my dropdown contains just one value (Male for a gender), I need to display all the values Male, Female, and give the user the ability to change it after populating the previously selected value

Comment: that's what `mav.addObject("statuses", EnumSet.allOf(Status.class));` is for. `mav` is ModelAndView object.

Comment: Ah gotcha . Thx

Comment: a quick question, can u also post an example with th:field instead of id and name attributes ?