# Spring how to use select with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Good day,
I was working on spring form and successfully run the spring provided guide for form

but the think was not there was select i would like to create the select field by given option and would like to know the user selected value

how can i achieve this.

thanks.

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495025/creating-drop-down-menu-and-form-in-thymeleaf/41101251#41101251

Comment: Your answer is showing how to print but i also want to get the selected value i am using class base model.

Comment: selected value will be passed back to controller with form object, the input field has a name and a value.